# disappearing divs when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

OK... I'm confused.  So I have some fields with a small question mark icon next to each one.  When a user hovers over the question mark, it changes to a pencil icon and displays an inline-tooltip.  When the user clicks on the icon, a modal should pop up to edit the content.  Everything works as it should, except when the icon is clicked, all of a sudden the following div vanishes.  If I comment out the `hover` part, though, the click action doesn't trigger the disappear.  I don't understand how the hover is activated on a click.  (I'm new to all of this, so any help/feedback greatly appreciated--even outside the scope of my question if you see improvements to my code).  Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
$('.tooltip').hover(
        function() { 
            $(this).find($('.icon-pencil')).css("display", "inline");
            $(this).find($('.question-mark')).css("display", "none")
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find($('.icon-pencil')).css("display", "none");
            $(this).find($('.question-mark')).css("display", "inline");
        }
)

$('.tooltip').click(function(){
    var id      = $(this).attr('tooltip-id');
    var tip     = $(this).attr('data-tooltip');
    var target  = $('#tooltip-modal');
    $("#tooltip_id").val(id);
    $("#tooltip_body").val(tip);
    $.fancybox(target);

});
```

That works on these divs (two of many with similar construction):

```
<div class="field-wrapper">
    <label class="label">Client Account</label>
    <input id="clientaccount_name" value="<?php if(!empty($client_account)){ echo $client_account["name"]; } ?>" class="input autocomplate"></input>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="small-top tooltip double-lines"  data-tooltip="<?php print(isset($tooltips['tooltip']['clientaccount_name']['desc']) ? $tooltips['tooltip']['clientaccount_name']['desc'] : 'n/a');?>" tooltip-id="<?php print(isset($tooltips['tooltip']['clientaccount_name']['id']) ? $tooltips['tooltip']['clientaccount_name']['id'] : 'n/a');?>"><span data-icon="&#xe014;" class="question-mark"></span><span class="icon-pencil"></span></a>
    <input id="clientaccount_id" type="hidden" name="clientaccount_id" value="<?php if(!empty($client_account)){ echo $client_account["id"];} ?>"></input>
</div>
<div class="field-wrapper">
    <label class="label">Client Short Code</label>
    <input id="client_shortcode" name="short_code" value="<?php echo $client_info["short_code"]; ?>" class="input small" maxlength="5"></input>             
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="small-top tooltip double-lines"  data-tooltip="<?php print(isset($tooltips['tooltip']['client_short_code']['desc']) ? $tooltips['tooltip']['client_short_code']['desc'] : 'n/a');?>" tooltip-id="<?php print(isset($tooltips['tooltip']['client_short_code']['id']) ? $tooltips['tooltip']['client_short_code']['id'] : 'n/a');?>"><span data-icon="&#xe014;" class="question-mark"></span><span class="icon-pencil"></span></a>                    
    <input id="old_shortcode" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $client_info["short_code"];?>" />
</div>
```

Comment: It will probably help us answer if you can set up a jsfiddle.

Comment: Happy to... but the css file is 6000 lines long and I'm not sure what parts are relevant.  What do people do in cases like this?  I assume pasting the whole thing would be poor form.

Comment: 6K CSS?  Yikes!  Prototype it for us, that ought to do it.  It need not be pixel perfect.

Comment: I'm having trouble... The code base I'm working with is quite large and even when I cut and paste the entire CSS, JS, and HTML files I'm working with, it doesn't look at all right.  

Maybe you can answer this:  How would commenting out a hover section stop something bad from happening on a click?  That makes no sense, right?

Comment: It's possible that calling $.fancybox(target); is briefly changing the element under the mouse pointer, and then the .hover() event goes off again.  Try commenting out the fancybox() line and see if that stops the div from disappearing.

Comment: Nope, no change.  The only way I can get the error to not happen is by commenting out the entire hover section, which still makes no sense to me.  

Also, in case I was unclear, it's the entire next div that disappears, which is an unrelated form, label, etc.  At no point should anything I do to the first div affect anything in the second.  (And it is always the immediately following div)

Comment: Why did I get a downvote?  I don't mind so much but if I'm doing something wrong, I don't know what it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out... there was another click handler buried deep in the javascript, so I changed the hover function (which introduced the class which had the handler attached) to read:

`$(this).find($('.icon-pencil')).css("display", "inline").unbind('click');`

and all is right with the world.  Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a fiddle or something, try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the containing div ( `.field-wrapper`)

Comment: Didn't work... see above for my difficulties with a fiddle.  Thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: I see. If you're not sure what parts are relevant, you should be able to isolate most of the relevant parts by using Firebug and inspecting the relevant elements.

Comment: Does Fiddle run PHP scripts as well?  It doesn't seem to, but maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: No, but all PHP does is create HTML. Javascript is applied against the resulting HTML from your PHP script, so PHP is irrelevant to debugging Javascript problems. If you have ajax scripts you want to debug, take an example output from the server side script and input it as a string to javascript for debugging purposes on fiddle.